# Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "checkUserExists", "signature": "checkUserExists(address)" }, code=BAD_DATA,

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

Here is my App.js file
App.js:

```
      `let signer = null;
       let provider=null;
        if (window.ethereum) {
            provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
            signer = await provider.getSigner();
        } else {
            console.log("MetaMask not installed; using read-only defaults");
            provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider();
        }

        const contract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi, signer);
        setMyContract(contract);           
        const address =await signer.getAddress();
        let present = await contract.checkUserExists(address);
```

`

Chat.sol:

```
`mapping(address => user) userList;
mapping(bytes32 => message[]) allMessages; 

function checkUserExists(address _pubkey) public view  returns (bool) {
    if( bytes(userList[_pubkey].name).length > 0){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}`
```

I'm getting the above error . please anyone help..

Comment: From the error message the function is returning an empty value "0x". It usually means the function has reverted.